# VB.Net Structure with lots of Shared functions. Is this proper/good use of a Struct?

Tags: vb.net, struct, operators, shared, user-defined-types

I have a Structure for a DAQ-channel user-defined-type called "**DAQChannel**".
It consists of only slot# and channel# variables.

- I'd prefer it to act like a value type, not a Class.
- I want to easily be able to cast **DAQChannel** as a standard datatype (**Integer, String,Double**) and vise-versa.

To do this I added many **CType(...)** and **New(...)** operators to the structure. All the functions are **Shared**, except for the New(...) routines.

- Will the Shared operators and subroutines keep the size the DAQChannel Type small?
- Or will it use up unnecessary amounts of memory if I am creating hundreds/thousands of DAQChannel instances or create a large array [DAQChannel()]?
- Is this the right way to do what I am trying to do?

Thanks

The 'New()' function in the Keysight34980A Class demos the **DAQChannel** structure.

```
Public Class Keysight34980A


    Public Sub New()

        Dim int As Integer
        Dim str As String
        Dim dbl As Double
        Dim my_chan1 As New DAQChannel(slot:=1, channel:=5)    '<-- construct from direct intput
        Dim my_chan2 As New DAQChannel(1005%)                  '<-- construct from Integer input
        Dim my_chan3 As New DAQChannel("2005")                 '<-- construct from String input


        '==========  DEMO type Conversion =========================
        my_chan1 = 1008%    '<-- from INT
        my_chan2 = "2030"   '<-- from String
        my_chan3 = 4066.0#  '<-- from Double
        int = my_chan2      '<-- to INT
        str = my_chan3      '<-- to String                  
        dbl = my_chan1      '<-- to Double


        '==========  DEMO COMPARE OPERATATIONs =========================
        my_chan1.slot = CardSlot.SLOT1 : my_chan1.channel = 5
        my_chan2 = "1005"
        my_chan3 = 2005.0#

        '-- Object to Object COMPARE
        If my_chan1 = my_chan2 Then MsgBox("my_chan1==my_chan2")     '<-- should be TRUE
        If my_chan1 = my_chan3 Then MsgBox("ERROR")                 '<-- should be FALSE
        If my_chan1 <> my_chan3 Then MsgBox("my_chan1 <> my_chan3")  '<-- should be TRUE


        '-- Object to String COMPARE
        If my_chan1 = "1005" And "1005" = my_chan1 Then
            '-- should be true
        Else
            MsgBox("ERROR")
        End If

        '-- Object to Int COMPARE
        If my_chan1 = 1005% And 1005% = my_chan1 Then
            '-- should be true
        Else
            MsgBox("ERROR")
        End If


        '==========  DEMO '+' OPERATATIONs =========================

        '-- Add Slot field(s) value
        my_chan1 = 5555%
        my_chan2 = "2015"
        my_chan3 = 3044.0#

        my_chan1 = my_chan2 + my_chan3.slot
        If my_chan1 = 3015 Then
            '-- should be true
        Else
            MsgBox("ERROR")
        End If

        my_chan1 = CardSlot.SLOT5 + my_chan3
        If my_chan1 = 5044 Then
            '-- should be true
        Else
            MsgBox("ERROR")
        End If


        '-- Add Channel field(s) value
        my_chan1 = 2050%
        my_chan2 = "3010"
        my_chan3 = 0#

        my_chan3 = my_chan1 + my_chan2.channel
        If my_chan3 = 2010 Then
            '-- should be true
        Else
            MsgBox("ERROR")
        End If

        my_chan3 = my_chan2 + 99US
        If my_chan3 = 3099 Then
            '-- should be true
        Else
            MsgBox("ERROR")
        End If



    End Sub


    '###################        DAQ CHANNEL STRUCTURE       ################################
    '#######################################################################################
    '
    '   DAQChannel
    '       |<------    slot    [CardSlot] {1-8}
    '       |<------    channel [UInt16] 
    '
    '   Also contains all type conversion code
    '
    '
    Public Structure DAQChannel

        Dim slot As CardSlot
        Dim channel As UInt16


        '******* CONSTRUCTORS (NOT SHARED) *******************************************
        '******* uses CONVERSION FUNCTIONS (SHARED), located below
        '****
        '**
        '-- construct directly
        Public Sub New(slot As CardSlot, channel As UInt16)
            Me.slot = slot : Me.channel = channel
        End Sub

        '-- construct from Int
        Public Sub New(input As Integer)
            ToSlotNChan(input, Me.slot, Me.channel)
        End Sub
        '-- construct from string
        Public Sub New(input As String)
            ToSlotNChan(input, Me.slot, Me.channel)
        End Sub
        '-- construct from double
        Public Sub New(input As Double)
            ToSlotNChan(input, Me.slot, Me.channel)
        End Sub
        '-- construct from Uint16
        Public Sub New(input As UInt16)
            ToSlotNChan(input, Me.slot, Me.channel)
        End Sub


        '******* TYPE CONVERSIONS (SHARED) *******************************************
        '****
        '**
        ' INT>>DAQChannel
        Public Shared Narrowing Operator CType(ByVal val As Integer) As DAQChannel
            Return New DAQChannel(val)
        End Operator
        ' INT<<DAQChannel
        Public Shared Widening Operator CType(ByVal DAQch As DAQChannel) As Integer
            Return (CInt(DAQch.slot) * 1000%) + CInt(DAQch.channel)
        End Operator
        '--------------------------------
        ' STRING>>DAQChannel
        Public Shared Narrowing Operator CType(ByVal val As String) As DAQChannel
            Return New DAQChannel(val)
        End Operator
        ' STRING<<DAQChannel
        Public Shared Widening Operator CType(ByVal DAQch As DAQChannel) As String
            Dim num As Integer
            num = (CInt(DAQch.slot) * 1000%) + CInt(DAQch.channel)
            Return Strings.Format(num, "0000")
        End Operator
        '--------------------------------
        ' DOUBLE>>DAQChannel
        Public Shared Narrowing Operator CType(ByVal val As Double) As DAQChannel
            Return New DAQChannel(val)
        End Operator
        ' DOUBLE<<DAQChannel
        Public Shared Widening Operator CType(ByVal DAQch As DAQChannel) As Double
            Return CDbl((CInt(DAQch.slot) * 1000%) + CInt(DAQch.channel))
        End Operator
        '--------------------------------
        ' UINT16>>DAQChannel
        Public Shared Narrowing Operator CType(ByVal val As UInt16) As DAQChannel
            Return New DAQChannel(val)
        End Operator
        ' UINT16<<DAQChannel
        Public Shared Widening Operator CType(ByVal DAQch As DAQChannel) As UInt16
            Return CDbl((CInt(DAQch.slot) * 1000%) + CInt(DAQch.channel))
        End Operator


        '******* OPERATORS (SHARED) ********************************************************
        '****
        '**
        'are STRUCTs EQUAL compare
        Public Shared Operator =(ByVal DAQch1 As DAQChannel,
                                ByVal DAQch2 As DAQChannel) As Integer
            Do
                If DAQch1.slot <> DAQch2.slot Then Exit Do
                If DAQch1.channel <> DAQch2.channel Then Exit Do
                Return True
            Loop While (False)
            Return False
        End Operator
        'are STRUCTs NOT EQUAL compare
        Public Shared Operator <>(ByVal DAQch1 As DAQChannel,
                                ByVal DAQch2 As DAQChannel) As Integer
            Return Not (DAQch1 = DAQch2)
        End Operator
        '-------------------------------------------------------
        '-------------------------------------------------------
        'is CHANNEL[Int] EQUAL compare
        Public Shared Operator =(ByVal DAQch As DAQChannel,
                                ByVal channel As Integer) As Integer
            Dim x As Integer = DAQch
            If x = channel Then Return True
            Return False
        End Operator
        'is CHANNEL[Int] NOT EQUAL compare
        Public Shared Operator <>(ByVal DAQch As DAQChannel, ByVal channel As Integer) As Integer
            Return Not (DAQch = channel)
        End Operator
        '-------------------
        'is CHANNEL[Int] EQUAL compare
        Public Shared Operator =(ByVal channel As Integer,
                                ByVal DAQch As DAQChannel) As Integer
            Return (DAQch = channel)
        End Operator
        'is CHANNEL[Int] NOT EQUAL compare
        Public Shared Operator <>(ByVal channel As Integer, ByVal DAQch As DAQChannel) As Integer
            Return Not (DAQch = channel)
        End Operator
        '-------------------------------------------------------
        '-------------------------------------------------------
        'is CHANNEL[String] EQUAL compare
        Public Shared Operator =(ByVal DAQch As DAQChannel,
                                 ByVal channel As String) As Integer
            Dim x As Double = DAQch
            If x = CDbl(channel) Then Return True
            Return False
        End Operator
        'is CHANNEL[String] NOT EQUAL compare
        Public Shared Operator <>(ByVal DAQch As DAQChannel, ByVal channel As String) As Integer
            Return Not (DAQch = channel)
        End Operator
        '-------------------
        'is CHANNEL[String] EQUAL compare
        Public Shared Operator =(ByVal channel As String,
                                 ByVal DAQch As DAQChannel) As Integer
            Return (DAQch = channel)
        End Operator
        'is CHANNEL[String] NOT EQUAL compare
        Public Shared Operator <>(ByVal channel As String, ByVal DAQch As DAQChannel) As Integer
            Return Not (DAQch = channel)
        End Operator
        '-------------------------------------------------------
        '-------------------------------------------------------
        'add slot[CardSlot] to [DAQChannel] Object
        Public Shared Operator +(ByVal DAQch As DAQChannel,
                                 ByVal slot As CardSlot) As DAQChannel
            Return New DAQChannel(slot:=slot, channel:=DAQch.channel)
        End Operator
        'add slot[CardSlot] to [DAQChannel] Object
        Public Shared Operator +(ByVal slot As CardSlot, ByVal DAQch As DAQChannel) As DAQChannel
            Return DAQch + slot
        End Operator
        '-------------------------------------------------------
        '-------------------------------------------------------
        'add Channel[Uint16] to [DAQChannel] Object
        Public Shared Operator +(ByVal DAQch As DAQChannel,
                                 ByVal channel As UInt16) As DAQChannel
            Return New DAQChannel(slot:=DAQch.slot, channel:=channel)
        End Operator
        'add Channel[Uint16] to [DAQChannel] Object
        Public Shared Operator +(ByVal channel As UInt16, ByVal DAQch As DAQChannel) As DAQChannel
            Return DAQch + channel
        End Operator




        '******* CONVERSION FUNCTIONS (SHARED) *******************************************
        '******* used in 'New(...)' constructors
        '****
        '**
        '-- INT conversion
        Private Shared Function ToSlotNChan(int As Integer, ByRef slot_o As CardSlot, ByRef chan_o As UInt16) As Integer
            Dim s As Integer
            Dim c As Integer
            On Error GoTo ConvERROR_45252

            If int < 0 Then GoTo ConvERROR_45252        '<-- quick error check

            s = CInt(int / 1000%)
            If s < 1 Or s > 8 Then GoTo ConvERROR_45252

            c = int - (s * 1000%)
            If c < 1 Or c >= 1000 Then GoTo ConvERROR_45252

            slot_o = s
            chan_o = c
            Return (s * 1000%) + c
ConvERROR_45252:
            slot_o = CardSlot.NA : chan_o = 0 : Return 0
        End Function


        '-- DOUBLE conversion
        Private Shared Function ToSlotNChan(dbl As Double, ByRef slot_o As CardSlot, ByRef chan_o As UInt16) As Integer
            Dim int As Integer
            On Error GoTo ConvERROR_45252

            int = CInt(dbl)
            If (dbl - CDbl(int)) <> 0# Then GoTo ConvERROR_45252

            Return ToSlotNChan(int, slot_o, chan_o)
ConvERROR_45252:
            slot_o = CardSlot.NA : chan_o = 0 : Return 0
        End Function


        '-- STRING conversion
        Private Shared Function ToSlotNChan(str As String, ByRef slot_o As CardSlot, ByRef chan_o As UInt16) As Integer
            Dim dbl As Double
            On Error GoTo ConvERROR_45252
            dbl = CDbl(str)
            Return ToSlotNChan(dbl, slot_o, chan_o)
ConvERROR_45252:
            slot_o = CardSlot.NA : chan_o = 0 : Return 0
        End Function


        '-- Uint16 conversion
        Private Shared Function ToSlotNChan(uint As UInt16, ByRef slot_o As CardSlot, ByRef chan_o As UInt16) As Integer
            Dim int As Integer
            On Error GoTo ConvERROR_45252
            int = CInt(uint)
            If (int - uint) <> 0# Then GoTo ConvERROR_45252

            Return ToSlotNChan(int, slot_o, chan_o)
ConvERROR_45252:
            slot_o = CardSlot.NA : chan_o = 0 : Return 0
        End Function


    End Structure


    '---- Card Slots enumerated -------------------
    Public Enum CardSlot
        NA = 0
        SLOT1 = 1
        SLOT2 = 2
        SLOT3 = 3
        SLOT4 = 4
        SLOT5 = 5
        SLOT6 = 6
        SLOT7 = 7
        SLOT8 = 8
    End Enum


End Class
```

Comment: Wondering if you might be better off deleting this question and moving it to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Maybe. I guess what I’m really trying to ask is if this is an inefficient/bad use of a struct; having all the shared functions.

Comment: Seems fine to me.  I'm not sure how there would be an efficiency problem; there's only one instance of the code under any circumstances.  You might want to consider making the data members `ReadOnly` as mutable `Structure`s are very hard to reason about correctly due to the language rules on when copies are taken.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Just to be clear, if the 'ToSlotNChan(..)' method was NOT Shared... Each CType(...) conversion would require an additional Instancing of the Structure, slowing down the code. Right?  CType(...) -- calls --> New(..) --calls--> ToSlotNChan(..)

Comment: I see no difference in speed. Probably because 'ToSlotNChan' is always called by an instance (in New(..)). If I was using a public method:  'DAQChannel.myFunc' then I think it would make a big difference using Shared modifier to avoid instancing.